# Is there any way to reuse workflows in a loop until we stop/disable the parent workflow manually?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

I was implementing some workflows and faced an [issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/8488) with reusable workflow depth limits.

Here is the requirement:

1. `WorkFlow1` (has two jobs) will take input and execute `Job1` & will pass the input value to `Job2`, which actually calls `WorkFlow2`
2. `WorkFlow2` (has two jobs) will take input and execute `Job1` & will pass the input value to `Job2` which calls `WorkFlow1`

The above two steps should run in a loop until we stop/disable `WorkFlow1` manually.

Is there any way to achieve this?

`WorkFlow1.yml`:

```yaml
name: To run bat tests on mac.
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version:
        description: 'release version.'
        required: true
        default: '1.0.0'
        type: string

    workflow_call:
    inputs:
      version:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  run-bat-tests: **#job1**
    runs-on:
      - self-hosted
      - label-1
    outputs:
      version: ${{ steps.version-no.outputs.version }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check the release version
        id: version-no
        run: |
          echo "version=${{ inputs.version }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "version=${{ inputs.version }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  uninstall-test: **#job2**
    if: ${{ always() }}
    needs: run-bat-tests
    uses: ./.github/workflows/WorkFlow2.yml
    with:
      version: ${{ needs.run-bat-tests.outputs.version }}
```

`WorkFlow2.yml`:

```yaml
name: To run uninstall test on mac.

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      version:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  run-mac-uninstall-test: **#job1**
    runs-on:
      - self-hosted
      - label-1
    outputs:
      version: ${{ steps.version-no.outputs.environment }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check the release version
        id: version-no
        run: |
          echo "version=${{ inputs.version }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "version=${{ inputs.version }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT


  trigger-bat-tests: **#job2**
    if: ${{ success() }}
    needs: run-mac-uninstall-test
    uses: ./.github/workflows/WorkFlow1.yml
    with:
      version: ${{ needs.run-mac-bat-tests.outputs.version }}
```

I tried looping the jobs, but I ended up with the issue mentioned above.